How can I modify Unity HRDP Visual Graph code?
I want to play around with Unity's VFX compute shaders.
Let's say I want to modify 2 files:

CollisionPlane.cs
CollisionBase.cs

I can find them in this path: My project\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualeffectgraph@14.0.10\Editor\Models\Blocks\Implementations\Collision\Collision*.cs
Suppose I modify CollisionPlane.cs, source string, save it, and maximize the editor. In that case, unity loads these changes, but then this file goes back to the original state before modifications and I have to Ctrl + Z to restore my modifications which is very annoying.
It gets more frustrating if I want to modify more than just one file, like CollisionBase.cs
What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Don't modify the library files. Copy them into your assets and modify your copies as you please

How would it work? I make a copy, modify, and copy and paste it into the lib files?

I think you should copy all files in Collision folder, and maybe do some renaming of files or classes, so that Unity can distinguish your version from original version

Alright, but how can I force unity to use my classes instead of the original?
